# Are the zero linear map and the identity projections?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

A projection is a linear map $T:V\to V$ such that $T^2=T$.

I know that projections can be diagonalized so that they take block form with an identity block and the rest being zeros.

How do $0$ and $I$ fit into this form?

Comment: So, do they satisfy $T^2=T$?

Comment: Is it true that $1^2=1$ and $0^2=0$? If so, can you apply this to solve your problem?

Comment: @Normal Human It's just that I saw somewhere that with respect to some basis a project can be written in the form of a block matrix with a particular identity say$ I_1 $or$ I_3$ or whatever in the top left corner and zeros everywhere else.

Comment: Okay, those blocks can have 0 size.

Comment: @Normal Human Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both zero and identity are projections.

The statement about bringing projections to a canonical form can be put as follows. Every projection in $n$ dimensions can be diagonalized so that the diagonal elements are 
$$
\underset{r\text{ times}}{\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}},\underset{n-r\text{ times}}{\underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}}
$$
where $r$ is the rank of the projection.

In the extreme cases $r=0$ and $r=n$ we get $0$ and $I$.